# How to Divide a String Into char Arrays

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, char

I am trying to divide a string into char arrays. I have a program that converts a char array (of 7 chars) from binary to ASCII text. So what I am trying to do is break a string up into char arrays of 7 chars in 'Arduino code' or in C, C++ or Java. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the program that I am using:

```
String getText(String str) {

  String text = "";

  char bits[] = "1001000";
  char new_char = 0;

  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {

    int current_bit = bits[i] - '0';
    new_char |= current_bit << (7-i);

  }

  text += (String) new_char + "";

  return text;

}
```

Comment: C doesn't even have a string type, per se, that's really any different from a character array.

Comment: The binary form of ASCII text ***is*** ASCII text.  You may be seeing work to be done where there is none.

Comment: If i give the program 7 binary bits (1001000) it will return the correct char. But I would like to have a program that could return the text value of a whole string of binary like: 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 to be converted to text

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
String s = "java";
char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
```

**UPDATE**
Well, I am watching this post after I saw a red (-2) point in my reputation list. And to my surprise the question is different from what it had been posted for Which I had answered. Now after reading your *Edited question* I am posting the *new answer* . You can use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method to achieve what you are looking for in **Java**. Here is the short demo of how this method could be used:

```
class  BinaryToWords
{
    static String returnString(String input)
    {
        String parts[] = input.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String part : parts)
        {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(part, 2);//Parses the string argument(part) as a signed integer in the radix(2).
            char ch = (char)i;
            sBuilder.append(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
        return sBuilder.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String binary = "1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100";//Input the binary format.
        System.out.println(returnString(binary));
    }
}
```

The output for the above code is:

```
Hello World
```

You can check this for other inputs too..And let me know if it working fine for all acceptable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? A C\C++ string is essentially an array of character.. If you have a pointer to a char (=string) then there's your array. Otherwise if you have an std::string, you can use its .c_str() method.

Comment: A string is not a pointer to a `char*`; it's a pointer to `char` --- where that `char` belongs to an array (explicit or implicit) and for which a subsequent element has the value `0`.